# Firebase Android inexplicable crash

Tags: android, sql

No data-related code is used in the project Most happened on Android 7.0 Most Samsung phones
The SDK that integrated a database before, I have deleted all and noted the references

```
    Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)
    #################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
    (cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1))
    #################################################################
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(SQLiteConnection.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:629)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:439)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:646)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.endTransaction
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkDatabase$1.onOpen(WorkDatabase.java:131)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkDatabase_Impl$1.onOpen(WorkDatabase_Impl.java:91)
    at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen(RoomOpenHelper.java:120)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase
    at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:328)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.cleanUp(ForceStopRunnable.java:135)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:79)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Comment: I have the same issue happen in Samsung Galaxy S10. Any idea?